# Eclipse as a uploader file to server

Tags: eclipse

i have just install Eclipse PDT on my linux desktop computer.
i am working on a project and should write some codes and uploading them on the server.
is it possible to upload the code directly on the server via Eclipse?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yup you can. Use [Eclipse RSE](http://www.eclipse.org/dsdp/tm/). Follow the link for more information: http://ikool.wordpress.com/2008/07/22/ssh-access-through-eclipse-rse/